# Protocol to implement Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms, azure-active-directory, adfs

I have a legacy ASP.NET Web Forms application. It is at present using on-prem ADFS with Cookie Authentication and WSFederation protocol.

We want to move it to Azure AD. I want to know whether I need to change WSFederation protocol or it too works with Azure AD. Also, is it required to change Cookie Authentication?

Code from Startup.CS is as below:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        //interactive logon process
        AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
        //name of the authentication type
        AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        //TODO: Enable this to always send and receive cookies in SSL when in production
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
        //enable sliding expiration
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        //Cookie expires in 4 hours
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4).Ticks)

    });

    app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
    {
        MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,
        Wtrealm = realm
    });
```

- Edited *

Code modified as below:

```
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        //interactive logon process
        AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
        //name of the authentication type
        AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        //Login path should be below
        // LoginPath = new PathString("login"),
        //TODO: Enable this to always send and receive cookies in SSL when in production
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
        //enable sliding expiration
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        //Cookie expires in 4 hours
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4).Ticks)

    });
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        MetadataAddress = AzureMetaData,
       Tenant = Tenant,
       Realm = Realm
                    

    });
```

Now it is throwing error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
> allowedAudience'

Comment: You want to know if it works or not? Did you try just running it and seeing if you ran into errors? There's no substitute for properly testing your code.

Comment: Azure AD supports WS-Fed.

Comment: @mason The code is running. I have no issues with the code. I just want to know if the same code would work with Azure AD as well or not?

Comment: You want to know if it works with Azure AD or not? Did you try just running it and seeing if you ran into errors? There's no substitute for properly testing your code.

Comment: @mason I executed updated code which I posted above. It throws error. I have mentioned.

Comment: Okay, so you provided an error message and that error seems pretty clear. What have you done to fix that error?

Comment: @mason Since I used Microsoft.IdentityModel, I tried to provide audience but the available audience parameter in this library is related to JWT. No idea further.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure AD supports WS-Fed. Ref: [Integrating a web app with Azure AD using WS-Federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation/)

For allowedAudiences, the value of this field has to match what is in the "audience" field of the token that is being sent to your service. You can go to the Azure AD app registration for your service and look in the manifest at the "identifierUris" field. The value here should match the value that you put in the Allowed Token Audiences list.

You can also go to https://resources.azure.com/ > drill down into the App Service resource > config > authsettings and correct allowedAudiences value:

```
"allowedAudiences":[
"https://mysite.azurewebsites.net"
  ]
```